# Routing and Membership

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-membership

I have a page that uses routing and it works fine under Visual web developer. But when I deployed to IIS 7. The page that uses routing doesn't seem to recognize the user is logged in.

I think I read about this but had not seen it until now. Hope there is a fix!

Environment deployed too is ASP.NET 3.5 SP1, SQL SERVER 2008, and IIS 7 integrated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the fix! As always

Apparently this needs to be in the web config.

I think this fixed it.